# Django unit test issue with thread and database interaction : database is being accessed by other users

Tags: python, django, postgresql, unit-testing

I have a Django project with the following View :

```
def base_task():
    # do something

def heavy_task():
    # do something with interaction with a PostgreSQL database

class MyView(generics.UpdateAPIView):

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        message_to_return, heavy_task_needed = base_task()

        if heavy_task_needed
            thread = Thread(target=heavy_task)
            thread.start()

        return JsonResponse(message_to_return, status=201)
```

This code returns a response to the client as fast as possible, and start some heavy processing on another thread.

I have some unit tests for this code :

```
class EndpointsTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ["segment.json", "raw_user.json"]

    def test_1(self):
        c = Client()
        body = {
            #some data
        }
        response = c.put(
            path=f"/my/endpoint/",
            data=json.dumps(body),
            content_type="application/json",
        )
    
        expected_body = to_json_comparable({
            #some data
        })
        self.assertEqual(response.content, expected_body)

    def test_2(self):
        c = Client()
        body = {
            #some data
        }
        response = c.put(
            path=f"/my/endpoint/",
            data=json.dumps(body),
            content_type="application/json",
        )
    
        expected_body = to_json_comparable({
            #some data
        })
        self.assertEqual(response.content, expected_body)
```

The issue I have is that, if multiple test cases trigger the `heavy_task` thread, my tests fail with this error :

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: database "my_db" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are X other sessions using the database.
```

Likely due to the fact that a new test has been started before the thread of the previous test has terminated. How can I solve this issue, as I can't wait for thread termination before returning JsonResponse, and not afterward either.